# where should I add an explicit lifetime bound?

Tags: rust

The compiler tells me to add an explicit lifetime bound, but I can’t figure out how I’m supposed to that.

```
    error[E0309]: the parameter type `E` may not live long enough
      --> src/main.rs:39:9
       |
    34 | impl<S: Into<juniper::Value>, E: Into<juniper::FieldError>> Registrable for FieldInfo<S,E>
       |                               -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `E: 'a +`
    ...
    39 |         Box::pin(to_graphql((self.resolver)(executor)))
       |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       |
    note: ...so that the type `impl std::future::Future` will meet its required lifetime bounds
      --> src/main.rs:39:9
       |
    39 |         Box::pin(to_graphql((self.resolver)(executor)))
       |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
server_1
    error[E0309]: the parameter type `S` may not live long enough
      --> src/main.rs:39:9
       |
    34 | impl<S: Into<juniper::Value>, E: Into<juniper::FieldError>> Registrable for FieldInfo<S,E>
       |      -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `S: 'a +`
    ...
    39 |         Box::pin(to_graphql((self.resolver)(executor)))
       |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       |
    note: ...so that the type `impl std::future::Future` will meet its required lifetime bounds
      --> src/main.rs:39:9
       |
    39 |         Box::pin(to_graphql((self.resolver)(executor)))
       |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the minimal code I came up with reproducing the error. It was working when `ReturnType1` was not generic over `V` and `E` but I’m now trying to make it work with multiple types:

```rust
use juniper;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Context {}

impl juniper::Context for Context {}

type ReturnType1<'a, V: Into<juniper::Value>, E: Into<juniper::FieldError>> = juniper::BoxFuture<'a, Result<V,E>>;
type InnerReturnType = juniper::ExecutionResult<juniper::DefaultScalarValue>;
type ReturnType<'a> = juniper::BoxFuture<'a, InnerReturnType>;

type Resolver<V: Into<juniper::Value>, E: Into<juniper::FieldError>> = for<'a> fn(
    &'a juniper::Executor<Context, juniper::DefaultScalarValue>
) -> ReturnType1<'a, V, E>;

async fn to_graphql<'a, V: Into<juniper::Value>, E: Into<juniper::FieldError>>(f: ReturnType1<'a, V, E>) -> InnerReturnType {
    f.await
        .map(|scalar| scalar.into())
        .map_err(|err| err.into())
}

trait Registrable: Send + Sync
{
    fn resolve<'a>(self: &Self, executor: &'a juniper::Executor<Context, juniper::DefaultScalarValue>) -> ReturnType<'a>;
}

struct FieldInfo<S, E>
where S: Into<juniper::Value>,
    E: Into<juniper::FieldError>
{
    resolver: Resolver<S,E>
}

impl<S: Into<juniper::Value>, E: Into<juniper::FieldError>> Registrable for FieldInfo<S,E>
where S: juniper::GraphQLType<TypeInfo=()> + Send + Sync
{
    fn resolve<'a>(self: &Self, executor: &'a juniper::Executor<Context, juniper::DefaultScalarValue>) -> ReturnType<'a>
    {
        Box::pin(to_graphql((self.resolver)(executor)))
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "pgql"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Mathieu Rochette <mathieu@texthtml.net>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
juniper = { git = "https://github.com/graphql-rust/juniper", branch = "master" }
```

What’s bothering me is that the generic type is declared on the `impl` block but the issue seems to be on the `fn` within, so adding a lifetime at the impl level seems the wrong way to go.

If I try to add a `where S: 'a, E: 'a` clause on the `fn resolve()`:

```rust
impl<S: Into<juniper::Value>, E: Into<juniper::FieldError>> Registrable for FieldInfo<S,E>
where S: juniper::GraphQLType<TypeInfo=()> + Send + Sync
{
    fn resolve<'a>(self: &Self, executor: &'a juniper::Executor<Context, juniper::DefaultScalarValue>) -> ReturnType<'a>
    where S: 'a, E: 'a {
        Box::pin(to_graphql((self.resolver)(executor)))
    }
}
```

it says the method does not match the trait declaration:

```
error[E0195]: lifetime parameters or bounds on method `resolve` do not match the trait declaration
  --> src/main.rs:37:15
   |
24 |     fn resolve<'a>(self: &Self, executor: &'a juniper::Executor<Context, juniper::DefaultScalarValue>) -> ReturnType<'a>;
   |               ---- lifetimes in impl do not match this method in trait
...
37 |     fn resolve<'a>(self: &Self, executor: &'a juniper::Executor<Context, juniper::DefaultScalarValue>) -> ReturnType<'a>
   |               ^^^^ lifetimes do not match method in trait
```

but I can’t add it on the trait since it does not know about `S` & `E`...

you can see the changes I’m trying to make in this PR : https://github.com/mathroc/pgql-rs/pull/1/files

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Specifically, *error[E0433]: failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate `context`?*

Comment: I’ll try to make a small example. thx the links @Shepmaster. It does not look like I can add a dependancy in Rust playground. I’ve just pushed to github what I have, and the modification I’m failling to make are in this PR : https://github.com/mathroc/pgql-rs/pull/1. I’ll try to make a brancher with everything not needed removed

Comment: I’ve reduced the code as much as I could and updated the answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the `await` in `to_graphql` might resolve any time in the lifetime of `f`—and when that happens the ensuing `into()` calls obviously require data in the respective types to be valid.  Ergo, `to_graphql`'s type parameters `V` and `E` must outlive its lifetime parameter `'a`.  The borrow checker enforces this implicitly, as documented under [`async` Lifetimes](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html#async-lifetimes):

> Unlike traditional functions, `async fn`s which take references or other non-`'static` arguments return a `Future` which is bounded by the lifetime of the arguments:

You want to specify that your implementation block's generic type parameters `S` and `E` have such a lifetime, but as you have noted you cannot add such a constraint when it does not appear in the trait definition.

One possibility is to add a lifetime parameter to the `Registrable` trait itself, and on the `resolve` function specify that this new trait lifetime parameter is a subtype of (i.e. outlives) the function's lifetime parameter `'a`:

```
trait Registrable<'b>: Send + Sync
{
    fn resolve<'a>(
        &self,
        executor: &'a juniper::Executor<Context, juniper::DefaultScalarValue>,
    ) -> ReturnType<'a>
    where 'b: 'a;
}
```

Then on your `impl` you can relate that lifetime parameter to your generic type parameters `S` and `E`:

```
impl<'b, S, E> Registrable<'b> for FieldInfo<S, E>
where
    S: juniper::GraphQLType<TypeInfo=()>,
    S: Send,
    S: Sync,
    S: Into<juniper::Value>,
    E: Into<juniper::FieldError>,
    S: 'b,
    E: 'b,
{
    fn resolve<'a>(
        &self,
        executor: &'a juniper::Executor<Context, juniper::DefaultScalarValue>,
    ) -> ReturnType<'a>
    where 'b: 'a
    {
        Box::pin(to_graphql((self.resolver)(executor)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting one. because we are implementing a trait, we can't add extra lifetime information to the function definition.

The issue at hand is that `S` and `E` are generic types, and therefore *may* contain references and hence be constrained by the lifetimes of those references. However they are generic and the compiler knows nothing about any constraints it may have.

At the same time, we are returning another generic type that depends on something with lifetime `'a` and `S` and `E`. `'a` is entirely unrelated to `S` and `E`, so the compiler looks and says: I can't tell if they live long enough because they are unrelated.

Now I haven't found the perfect way to describe this fully, however, we can make this work in a limited way with an easy code change - we can limit `S` and `E` to have static lifetimes, (which means they contain no references or only static references). This is usually sufficient in practice.

The code change in question is on `FieldInfo`:

```rust
struct FieldInfo<S, E>
where
    S: Into<juniper::Value> + 'static,
    E: Into<juniper::FieldError> + 'static,
{
    resolver: Resolver<S, E>,
}
```

I feel that there should be a way of expressing the lifetime relationships better, but I have yet to find it.

Comment: interesting, I can’t really understand why, but it works ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `where S: 'a` to `where S: 'a, E: 'a` to make sure `E` also lives long enough.

Comment: if I add this, the `E0309` error disappears but it still won’t work. I’ve update the question to explain this better